# Convert video from mov to MP4 in iOS xamarin

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

How to convert mov to MP4 in xamarin iOS. I am using AVAssetExportSession. Last few seconds of video gets chipped off.. Any solution for this to retain full video duration.

Here is my code.

```
var basePath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
        var inputFilePath = Path.Combine(basePath, Path.ChangeExtension(_vm.Model.AnswerName, "mov"));
        var outputFilePath = Path.Combine(basePath, _vm.Model.AnswerName);

        var asset = AVAsset.FromUrl(NSUrl.FromFilename(inputFilePath));

        AVAssetExportSession export = new AVAssetExportSession(asset, AVAssetExportSession.PresetHighestQuality);

        export.OutputUrl = NSUrl.FromFilename(outputFilePath);
        export.OutputFileType = AVFileType.Mpeg4;
        export.ShouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = true;

   try
        {
            export.ExportTaskAsync().Wait();


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex);
        }

        var fileHelper = new FileHelper();

        // If Export successful then delete the MOV file
        if (fileHelper.FileExists(_vm.Model.AnswerName))
        {
            fileHelper.DeleteFile(Path.ChangeExtension(_vm.Model.AnswerName, "mov"));
        }
```

Comment: Try to use `AVAssetExportSession.PresetPassthrough` instead.

Comment: Tried gives same issue

Comment: Resolved issue thanks everyone..

Comment: @PrachiKarapurkar how did you resolve this?